# CSS - Show both linear and radial backgrounds together

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I want a background that has both linear and radial gradients. The linear should display a `blue->white` gradient and the radial should display a polka dot pattern on top of it. I followed the guide on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp) but I cant get them both to display at the same time. I have attached a codesandbox for this problem. Can anyone please help me out and tell me what I am missing here?

I want something like this

[image]

But instead of stars it should show circles and they need to cover the whole page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>

    <style>
      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        /* Controls size of dot */
        background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff 44%, #01a2ce 100%, #ffffff 0%),
          radial-gradient(black 20%, white 20%);
        /* Controls Spacing, First value will scale width, second, height between dots */
        background-size: auto, 50px, 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h3>
        I want to display both the linear and radial backgrounds here. Linear
        will show the blue->white gradiant and radial will show the black polka
        dots.
      </h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can add background image of png format, and you will get that you want

Comment: That is an option but its a restrictive one. Even if I am able to find a background that exactly fits my requirements I wont be able to change it afterward (the colors, the size of the circles etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct you gradient like below:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
    /* the radial on the top and a transparent color at the end */
    radial-gradient(black 20%, transparent 21%), 
    linear-gradient(#ffffff 44%, #01a2ce 100%);
  background-size: 50px 50px, auto; /* no comma between 50px and 50px*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes. I was using white in the radial background that was overriding the color of the linear background! Great catch, thank you so much.